# Unable to send email through Exchange SMTP

Tags: email, smtp

I'm trying to send email through a Microsoft Exchange SMTP server using the Communicate Tool in EE admin. When I try to send an email, the browser spins for 5-10 seconds and then I get the following error message:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to send email at this time.

220 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 10 Dec 2014 07:52:35 -0600 

hello: 

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

I know my settings in EE's Email Configuration are good. I've tested connecting to the Exchange server and sending email through both telnet and a PHP script and those both worked. And yet, ExpressionEngine won't send mail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For Exchange, there are a couple of [configuration overrides](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html) that you need to set for email to work:

```
$config['email_crlf']    = "\r\n";
$config['email_newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Add those, restart your server, and you should be good to go.

**Note**: Make sure to use those double quotes around the `\r\n` strings.

Comment: Finding this answer years later. Saved my rear! Thanks!